# how can i transfer tokens to many addresses with lowest transaction fee?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

i know i can write function that iterate through on list of addresses and transfer tokens to those addresses with one transaction.
But this solution is very expensive when the number of addresses increases. I want to send these tokens every 24 hours (Neither forward nor backward, at a particular moment).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [disperse.app](https://disperse.app/)

It supports many networks and you can also use it to send ETH to multiple addresses in one transaction.